# kafka does not work when broker 0 fails

Tags: apache-kafka

https://kafka.apache.org/quickstart

```
bin/kafka-topics.sh --describe --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic my-replicated-topic
Topic:my-replicated-topic   PartitionCount:1    ReplicationFactor:3 Configs:
    Topic: my-replicated-topic  Partition: 0    Leader: 1   Replicas: 2,0,1 Isr: 1,0
```

If I kill broker 0, consumer cannot receive any msgs.
However, if broker 1or2 is killed, it still works.

Comment: which consumer do you use?

Comment: bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --from-beginning --topic my-replicated-topic

Answer (score 0):

- try using broker IDs from 1 onwards.
- make sure all hostnames are resolvable
- give the client/consumer all three host names in the initial connect string